# Apex remote call outs are taking way too much time while logged in as Standard User when compared to being logged in as System Admin

Tags: apex, callout

In our company we use Salesforce as a backend server and database for our website. When I log in as a system administrator the apex remote call outs are really fast and don't take more than 1-6 seconds for each call. But, the problem comes when I log in as a Standard user. The apex call outs take more than 15 seconds for each call out.

I have checked internet connection, API side and apex classses e.t.c everything. Everything is same for both the cases except for type of user being logged in.

Do these both users have different limitations of any kind?

Comment: It should have no effect. However, if you're unsure, you can contact Support for more help.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Can you describe how you are making callouts from Salesforce to your website?  If SF is your backend database, why do you need to make these callouts from SF to the site?  Please [edit] your post.

Comment: Have never observed this and have tested a large amount of different callouts as Admin in the wake of launching new web services. Are your callouts unauthenticated? If not, do you use the same authentication when testing as Admin?